# "Find All References" broken in one solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2005, find-all-references

At some point "Find All References" feature got broken for a single solution that I have.  It works in all other solutions.  For this one, it always returns "Search found no results"

What could be the problem?

Comment: Problem located.  It was caused by the following line in the AssemblyInfo.cs:

[assembly: AssemblyKeyFileAttribute("myKey.snk")]

Removing it did the trick. Not sure why.

Comment: @Rich B - good edit / rescue; appreciated.

Comment: The second edit was pretty funny though.

Comment: I still wonder why I was suspended for 2 days given that OP liked my edit... hmm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the old days (VC6 :) ) this type of problem was often fixed by deleting the .ncb file and letting it be rebuilt automatically. Not sure if this is still true in VS2005/8.

Comment: +1, deleting the NCB should fix this on VS 2k5 and 2k8 as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would kill all instances of Visual Studio and try again.  If this doesn't work, I would imagine that there really *are* no references to the type or member you are looking for.

Since this feature is working for other solutions I find it hard to believe that this is an issue with the IDE itself.  I think the most likely explanation is that the IDE is correct and you actually have no references.

Do you have two types that are similarly named but not actually the same type?  Can you find the references by text search?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem in VS 2008. In my case it was because I was opening the web site as a project, instead of doing File - Open Web Site.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I have been stumbled by "Search returned no results" but quickly realized that method name was Finalize().  Once renamed, all was well.